# How to add a second different app to existing Google Play account?

Tags: android, google-play

I have successfully set up a  [Google play account](https://play.google.com) and created an APP that is currently active.

I am curious how to add a second DIFFERENT app to the account so that I can have two applications Active at one time? Is there any special settings?

In Google Play - I see a button + Add New App - is it that simple or is there more to do?

What about the keystore - can I use the same one as the first app or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is that simple... Just click in "add new app" and upload a new Apk to Google Play. Your new apk just must have a different applicationId. Google Play will request to create a whole Store Listing for your new App.

You can use same keystore.. According to:

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

```
//Signing Considerations
//You should sign all of your apps with the same certificate throughout the expected lifespan of your applications.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any special settings?

No, there is no special settings you have to do same as previous app.

> In Google Play - I see a button + Add New App - is it that simple or
>   is there more to do?

No Additional work same as previous app.

> What about the keystore - can I use the same one as the first app or
>   do I need to do something else?

yes, you can use same key store for multiple app. even its good idea that every app have same key store. *just check key store expire date.*

---

***Additional work: only when you app support new things then previous app like your app support android wear, android Tv, In-App Purchase, application is GAME in these case you have to do some additional works depending on your app requirement.***

every help available on [Google Play Help Center](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en#topic=3450769) so its not too hard!